# how to change the interval of setInterval while its ruining when the user hold shift key?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve a feature that when the user press and holds the shift key, the player will speed up; when the user releases the shift key, the player back to normal speed. My code right now will increase the speed recursively while holding the shift key and I don't know why. please help me fix it.

```js
button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  my_game = setInterval(game, speed);
});

window.onload = function() {
 canv = document.getElementById("gc");
 context = canv.getContext("2d");
 document.addEventListener ("keydown", keyPush);
 document.addEventListener ("keyup", keyRelease);
}

function keyPush(keyEvent) {
 switch(keyEvent.keyCode) {
  case 16:
   clearInterval(my_game);
   speed *= 0.1; 
   my_game = setInterval(game, speed);
   break;
 }
}

function keyRelease(keyEvent) {
 switch(keyEvent.keyCode) {
  case 16:
   clearInterval(my_game);
   speed /= 0.1;
   my_game = setInterval(game, speed);
   break;
 }
}
```

Comment: *increase the speed recursively* — what does that mean?

Comment: Do not change the interval, just change the amount you move the player each interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a constant for the normal speed and decrease/decrease that constant just once when the user press the key, not every time the key is pressed: `speed *= 0.1;`

```js
var NORMAL_SPEED = 1;

button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  my_game = setInterval(game, speed);
});

window.onload = function() {
 canv = document.getElementById("gc");
 context = canv.getContext("2d");
 document.addEventListener ("keydown", keyPush);
 document.addEventListener ("keyup", keyRelease);
}

function keyPush(keyEvent) {
 switch(keyEvent.keyCode) {
  case 16:
   clearInterval(my_game);
   speed = NORMAL_SPEED * 0.1; 
   my_game = setInterval(game, speed);
   break;
 }
}

function keyRelease(keyEvent) {
 switch(keyEvent.keyCode) {
  case 16:
   clearInterval(my_game);
   speed = NORMAL_SPEED;
   my_game = setInterval(game, speed);
   break;
 }
}
```